# Work out rolling sums for variables with non-consecutive days in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, zoo

I have some data on which I'd like to work out the win % across a rolling 14 day window thoughout around 7 years worth of results. The days are non-consecutive so whenever I group by the 'Trainer' variable and run `rollapplyr` or `runSum`/ `sum_run`, I get the past 14 events summarised but can't figure out how to get the 14 days grouped. When I try to define the width or k value using the day from the date, I get an error

> invalid time series parameters specified

or `vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs`

Edit- Below code gives the error above

```
df %>% group_by(Trainer) %>% mutate(Fourteen_day_wins =             rollapplyr(Wins, width = 1:n() - findInterval( Date %d-% Days(14), Date), sum)) %>%  ungroup
```

I'd like to get the total wins and count of events for a 14 day rolling period when grouped by Trainer in new columns in my df. Could someone point me in the right direction please? Still an R novice so has stumped me so far!

Sample df:

```
structure(list(Trainer = c("Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J",  "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J",  "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie",  "Haggas, W J"), Wins = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 0, 1, 0, 0), Date = structure(c(1508025600, 1508112000, 1508112000,  1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508284800, 1508284800, 1508457600,  1508457600, 1508544000, 1508544000, 1508544000, 1508716800, 1508716800,  1508716800, 1508803200, 1508803200, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508889600,  1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1509062400,  1509062400, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509148800, 1509148800,  1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509321600, 1509321600,  1509321600, 1509321600, 1509494400, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509753600,  1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600,  1510099200, 1510099200, 1510099200, 1510358400, 1510358400, 1510358400,  1521936000, 1521936000, 1523923200, 1523923200, 1523923200, 1524009600,  1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600,  1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000,  1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524182400, 1524182400,  1524182400, 1524268800, 1524268800, 1524268800, 1524528000, 1524528000,  1524528000, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524614400, 1524614400, 1524787200,  1524787200, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1525132800, 1525219200,  1525219200, 1525219200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck error code added above. It's the last 14 days I'd like please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments to findInterval should be numeric and ordered.

To address this convert the dates to Date class and then numeric so that d below is the number of days since the Epoch.  Now we can use it with findInterval as shown.  If the data were already sorted the arrange line could be omitted.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  arrange(Trainer, Date) %>%
  group_by(Trainer) %>%
  mutate(d = as.numeric(as.Date(Date)), 
         Wins14 = rollapplyr(Wins, 1:n() - findInterval(d - 14, d), sum)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-d)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 101 x 4
   Trainer           Wins Date                Wins14
   <chr>            <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl>
 1 Appleby, Charlie     1 2017-10-15 00:00:00      1
 2 Appleby, Charlie     1 2017-10-18 00:00:00      2
 3 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-18 00:00:00      2
 4 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-23 00:00:00      2
 5 Appleby, Charlie     1 2017-10-25 00:00:00      3
 6 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-25 00:00:00      3
 7 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-25 00:00:00      3
 8 Appleby, Charlie     1 2017-10-25 00:00:00      4
 9 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-27 00:00:00      4
10 Appleby, Charlie     0 2017-10-27 00:00:00      4
# ... with 91 more rows
```

Comment: Just run this over my larger data and has worked perfectly! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use `complete` to complete your data and then use 14 window period

```
df %>%
       group_by(Trainer) %>%
       complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), '1 day')) %>%
       mutate(runMeans = zoo::rollmean(Wins, 14,0,na.rm = TRUE))
    # A tibble: 459 x 4
    # Groups:   Trainer [2]
       Trainer          Date                 Wins runMeans
       <chr>            <dttm>              <dbl>    <dbl>
     1 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-15 00:00:00     1    0    
     2 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-16 00:00:00    NA    0    
     3 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-17 00:00:00    NA    0    
     4 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-18 00:00:00     1    0    
     5 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-18 00:00:00     0    0    
     6 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-19 00:00:00    NA    0    
     7 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-20 00:00:00    NA    0.429
     8 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-21 00:00:00    NA    0.429
     9 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-22 00:00:00    NA    0.429
    10 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-23 00:00:00     0    0.375
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the combination of all days and all trainers, merge it with the original data and then use a 14-day window:

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Trainer = c("Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J", "Appleby, Charlie", "Appleby, Charlie", "Haggas, W J"), Wins = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), Date = structure(c(1508025600, 1508112000, 1508112000, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508284800, 1508284800, 1508457600, 1508457600, 1508544000, 1508544000, 1508544000, 1508716800, 1508716800, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508803200, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1508889600, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509062400, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509148800, 1509321600, 1509321600, 1509321600, 1509321600, 1509494400, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1509753600, 1510099200, 1510099200, 1510099200, 1510358400, 1510358400, 1510358400, 1521936000, 1521936000, 1523923200, 1523923200, 1523923200, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524009600, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524096000, 1524182400, 1524182400, 1524182400, 1524268800, 1524268800, 1524268800, 1524528000, 1524528000, 1524528000, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524614400, 1524614400, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1524787200, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525219200, 1525219200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

all_dates <- with(df, expand_grid(Trainer = unique(Trainer), 
                                  Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by="1 day")))

all_dates <- left_join(all_dates, df)
#> Joining, by = c("Trainer", "Date")

all_dates %>% 
  group_by(Trainer) %>% 
  mutate(win_pct = rollapplyr(Wins, 
                              width=14, 
                              mean, 
                              partial = TRUE, 
                              align="right", 
                              na.rm=TRUE, 
                              fill=TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 460 × 4
#> # Groups:   Trainer [2]
#>    Trainer          Date                 Wins win_pct
#>    <chr>            <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-15 00:00:00     1   1    
#>  2 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-16 00:00:00    NA   1    
#>  3 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-17 00:00:00    NA   1    
#>  4 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-18 00:00:00     1   1    
#>  5 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-18 00:00:00     0   0.667
#>  6 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-19 00:00:00    NA   0.667
#>  7 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-20 00:00:00    NA   0.667
#>  8 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-21 00:00:00    NA   0.667
#>  9 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-22 00:00:00    NA   0.667
#> 10 Appleby, Charlie 2017-10-23 00:00:00     0   0.5  
#> # … with 450 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: running `mean(all_dates$Wins[1:14], na.rm = T)` gives me `0.429` but your code produces `0.667`

Comment: @onyambu you're assuming that the `NA` dates should be treated as 0 rather than disregarded.  That may, in fact, be the appropriate way to treat them, but it's not obvious from the question.

Comment: No i am in no way treating NA as 0 but rather removing them. Check your own code. run the first mean of the first 14 days. `mean(all_dates$Wins[1:14], na.rm = T)` it wont give 0.667. Anyway seems OP did not care about filling the dates

Comment: @onyambu if you look at the 14th day for the first `Trainer`, its `win_pct` is the same number you generate (0.429).  The numbers before then (e.g., the 13the value, which is 0.5) are created using the previous 13 values.   If you look at the output in your answer, you've generated a mean of 0.429 with three non-missing values (1,1,0).  Seems to me like the value should be 2/3=.667.